# delay a function call on button click - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to delay a function call on button click using javascript in a manner when you click the button it should delay for like 3 or 5 seconds before calling the function. This is my snippet:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myButton').on('click', myFunction);

  setTimeout(function() { 
    myFunction(); 
  }, 5000);

  function myFunction() {
    var text = $(".total").text();
    alert(text);
  }
});
```

How can I get it right such that the function is called only when the button is clicked with a delay of 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code, I done some changes in your code snippet :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myButton').on('click', function(){
    setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);
  });

  function myFunction() {
    var text = $(".total").text();
    alert(text);
  } 
});
```

Comment: why won't it be in scope @mplungjan ? JavaScript declares functions/variables at the beginning of each execution context.

Comment: Please include a description of what the issue is. This site is for educating the question asker and also future visitors, not just spoonfeeding solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're providing the reference to `myFunction()` to the click handler, hence it's called immediately.

Instead you need to put the `setTimeout()` call in an anonymous function that you provide to the `click`. You also need to place the `myFunction()` definition in scope of the `window` so that it's available from the `setTimeout()` call. Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#myButton').on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);
  });        
});

function myFunction() {
  var text = $(".total").text();
  alert(text);
}
```

Comment: You need to adjust the delay time.

Comment: myFunction does however still need to be in scope when setTimeout runs

Comment: @claudios why? That section is copied verbatim from the quiestion, and is a 5 second delay as requested

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yes. No issue with your answer. I see last previous comment that the function call was not delayed.

Comment: our solutions are almost the same, just where the `setTimout` function is invoked. I do wonder which of the two options is "better practice" so to speak. I would usually try to keep whatever is in the `.on(...)` as short as possible, though maybe you prefer including the `setTimeout` there for another reason?

Comment: @Webeng either is fine, it just depends on the logic of the page. If you always want the logic of `myFunction()` to be delayed then it would make sense to put the `setTimeout()` in there. Alternatively if there's cases where it should sometimes happen immediately, then you'd need to wrap the call manually.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - it seems At least in Chrome, that the function IS in scope without having been defined outside the $(function() {}). I am surprised. https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/dom51ozg/

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').on('click', myFunction);
    function myFunction() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            var text = $(".total").text();
            alert(text);
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```